# Newbie Question: Read and Process a List of Text Files

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm completely new to .NET and am trying as a first step to write a text processing program. The task is simple: I have a list of 10,000 text files stored in one folder, and I'm trying to read each one, store it as a string variable, then run it through a series of functions, then save the final output to another folder. So far I can only manage to manually input the file path like this (in VB.NET):

```
 Dim tRead As System.IO.StreamReader

    Public Function ReadFile() As String

        Dim EntireFile As String

        tRead = File.OpenText("c:\textexample\00001.txt")

        EntireFile = tRead.ReadToEnd

        Return EntireFile

    End Function

 Public Function Step1()
  .....
 End Function

 Public Function Step2()
  .....
 End Function
  ..............
```

I'm wondering, therefore, if there's a way to automate this process. Perhaps for example store all input file path into a text file then read each entry at a time, then save the final output into the save path, again listed in a text file. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. 
ReplyQuote

Answer (score 4):

You're making it too complicated, it's only 3 lines of code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\")
    For Each File As String In Files
        Process(IO.File.ReadAllText(File))
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub Process(ByVal s As String)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just read all the files from the directory instead using [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx).  See the example at the bottom of the page.  Then use [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) to read all the text in the file to a string.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine a couple of System.IO classes with the Select extension method to read the files into an IEnumerable, like so...

```
Directory.GetFiles(myDir, "*.txt").Select(_
    Function(fileName) File.ReadAllText(fileName))
```

You could even extend the lambda expression you pass to Select to do whatever processing is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Something to get you started:

```
   var files = from file in new DirectoryInfo(@"YourPath").GetFiles()
                    select file;

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
            {
                // Do Stuff
                //string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

        }
```